# warning: ‘struct tag’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration void func(struct tag v);

Tags: c, struct, parameters, scope, namespaces

I am trying to execute the following program but inturn compiler is generating errors. I am presuming that program is correct and I have included function prototype in the beginning of the program. But without function prototype the program is working without errors. (i.e. first function definition and later main function). And I want to know where my understanding is not correct.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(struct tag v);

struct tag {
    int i;
    char c;
};
  
/*
void func(struct tag v)
{
    printf("%d %c\n", v.i, v.c);
    return;
}
*/

int main()
{
    /*struct tag {
        int i;
        char c;
    };*/
    struct tag var = {2, 's'};
    func(var);  

    return 0;
}

void func(struct tag v)
{
    printf("%d %c\n", v.i, v.c);
    return;
}
```

Output:

```
root@bhaskar:/home/bhaskar/Downloads/practice/cpractice/cindepth/struct# gcc p11_excer_1_4.c 
p11_excer_1_4.c:3:18: warning: ‘struct tag’ declared inside parameter list will not be visible outside of this definition or declaration
 void func(struct tag v);
                  ^~~
p11_excer_1_4.c: In function ‘main’:
p11_excer_1_4.c:17:7: error: type of formal parameter 1 is incomplete
  func(var);
       ^~~
p11_excer_1_4.c: At top level:
p11_excer_1_4.c:22:6: error: conflicting types for ‘func’
 void func(struct tag v)
      ^~~~
p11_excer_1_4.c:3:6: note: previous declaration of ‘func’ was here
 void func(struct tag v);
      ^~~~
```

Comment: Remember to declare structures *before* they are used.

Comment: Please use a consistent indentation style.

Answer (score 4):

Reverse the order of the declarations:

```c
struct tag {
    int i;
    char c;
};

void func(struct tag v);
```

Even better, reorder everything so you don't need to declare in advance, you can just define:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

struct tag {
    int i;
    char c;
};
  

void func(struct tag v)
{
    printf("%d %c\n", v.i, v.c);
}


int main()
{
    struct tag var = {2, 's'};
    func(var);  

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler needs to know about structures and such before they're used. It can't skip ahead to find out more.

To avoid excessive copying, it's generally suggested to pass in pointers to structures, as in:

```c
void func(struct tag* v)
{
    printf("%d %c\n", v->i, v->c);
}
```

Then when called:

```c
func(&var);
```

While this `struct` is of a fairly trivial size, that's usually not the case, so being familiar with this technique is important. It's not uncommon for a `struct` to weigh as much as 1MB or more, depending on contents, and copying it could be painful.

There's also no need, nor reason to `return` at the end of a `void` function. That's the default behaviour.

Comment: You are correct @tadman. I was simply inter changed the function prototype and structure declaration. But one more question, why this is not true for implicit data types such as int, char, float inside the function prototype.

Comment: Those fundamental types are always defined. There's no need to import declarations for them. That list is fairly short, though, and does not include even humble things like `uint8_t` or `bool`.

Answer (score 0):

There is two issues here:

- If the structure is used as a type it should be declared with typedef.
- You need to declare your structure first before you can actually reference it.

Working Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct{
    int i;
    char c;
}tag;

void func(tag v)
{
    printf("%d %c\n", v.i, v.c);
    return;
}

int main()
{
    tag var = {2, 's'};
    func(var);  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do never use `typedef struct { .... } foo;`, foreward declaration will become impossible. Better would be to not use typedef for `struct` or use the same name for the `struct` and `typedef`, like so `typedef struct foo { ..... } foo;` or use a very clear and defined way to create one name from the other.

Comment: Forward declaration point is correct. This way the struct has no name and the type has the name for the struct. Using typedef struct foo { ..... } foo; is safer.

Comment: Btw. Interesting user number.

Answer (score 0):

According to the C Standard (6.2.1 Scopes of identifiers)

> 2 For each different entity that an identifier designates, the
> identifier is visible (i.e., can be used) only within a region of
> program text called its scope. Different entities designated by the
> same identifier either have different scopes, or are in different name
> spaces. **There are four kinds of scopes: function, file, block, and
> function prototype. (A function prototype is a declaration of a
> function that declares the types of its parameters.)**

So the declaration of the type struct tag of the parameter of the function

```
void func(struct tag v);
```

is visible only within the function prototype declaration.

So you declared incomplete type `struct tag` that is not the same as the declaration after the function of a structure

```
void func(struct tag v);

struct tag {
    int i;
    char c;
};
```

You should declare the structure before declaring the function.

Take into account that there is a difference between C and C++ relative to such a function declaration.

Opposite to C in C++ the parameter declaration has the so-called elaborated type specifier and it becomes visible in the scope where the function is declared.

Also bear in mind that in general it is better to pass an object of the structure type by reference through a pointer to it instead of passing it by value creating a copy of it.

You could write in your program

```
struct tag {
    int i;
    char c;
};

void func( const struct tag *v);

//...

func( &var );

//...

void func( const struct tag *v)
{
    printf("%d %c\n", v->i, v->c);
}
```

(Node: The return statement in your function definition is redundant.)